# What is the normal approximation of the multinomial distribution?

Tags: normal-distribution, multinomial-distribution, approximation

If there are multiple possible approximations, I'm looking for the most basic one.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can approximate it with the multivariate normal distribution in the same way that binomial distribution is approximated by univariate normal distribution.  Check [Elements of Distribution Theory](http://books.google.ca/books?id=QsVl8FDmld8C&pg=PA378&lpg=PA378&dq=normal%20approximation%20multinomial%20distribution&source=bl&ots=NKg5cRWrBP&sig=tTxhtTW8uZEXe31aL6zkGQCMQFA&hl=en&sa=X&ei=qKYuUJ2vCMLb0QHU54Eo&ved=0CEcQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=normal%20approximation%20multinomial%20distribution&f=false) and [Multinomial Distribution](http://www.stat.umn.edu/geyer/5102/notes/brand.pdf) pages 15-16-17.

Let $P=(p_1,...,p_k)$ be the vector of your probabilities. Then the mean vector of the multivariate normal distribution is $ np=(np_1,np_2,...,np_k)$. The covariance matrix is a $k \times k$ symmetric matrix. The diagonal elements are actually the variance of $X_i$'s; i.e.$ np_i(1-p_i)$, $i=1,2...,k$. The off-diagonal element in the ith row and jth column is $\text{Cov}(X_i,X_j)=-np_ip_j$,  where $i$ is not equal to $j$.

Comment: I guess my statistical sophistication is not enough to connect the dots in this answer. If I have the sample size n and the probabilities P, how do I calculate the mean vector and the covariance matrix of the multivariate normal distribution?

Comment: Check out the 2nd reference.

Comment: Stat, so that this answer can stand by itself (and be resistant to link rot), would you mind giving a summary of the solution?

Comment: Let P=(p_1,...,p_k) be the vector of your probabilities. Then the mean vector of the multivariate normal distribution is np=(np_1,np_2,...,np_k). The covariance matrix is a k X k symmetric matrix. The diagonal elements are actually the variance of X_i's i.e. np_i(1-p_i), i=1,2...,k. The off diagonal element in the ith row and jth column is Cov(X_i,X_j)=-np_ip_j,  where i is not equal to j.

Comment: Does this need a continuity correction? How would you apply it?

Comment: The covariance matrix is not positive definite, but rather positive semi-definite, and is not full-rank. This makes the resulting multinormal distribution undefined. This is the problem I faced. Any idea how to handle it?

Comment: @M.Alaggan: The mean/covariance matrices defined here have one minor issue: For a multinomial distribution with $k$ variables, the equivalent multivariate normal has $k-1$ variates. This is evident in the simple binomial example, which is approximate by the (ordinary) normal distribution. For further discussion, see Example 12.7 of [Elements of Distribution Theory](https://www.amazon.com/dp/1107630738).

Comment: @M.S.Dousti in the case of the binomial example you get $$\Sigma = \begin{bmatrix} n p_1(1-p_1)&-n p_1p_2 \\ -np_1p_2& np_2(1-p_2)\end {bmatrix}$$ which is a bivariate variable (number of successes and failures) that has it's components fully correlated $$\frac{-np_1p_2}{\sqrt {np_1 (1-p_1)np_2 (1-p_2)}}=-1$$ where you need to use $p_1+p_2=1$ So, I consider this not so much an issue. It only means that the distribution in k variables are in a hyperplane of the k-dimensional space and could be reduced to k-1 variables, but it does not make the expression in terms of k variables a problem/issue.

Comment: I'd say that the distribution restricted to the hyperplane is not _exactly_ trivial, but the result is established enough that it's on wikipedia: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Degenerate_case

Answer (score 2):

The density given in [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/34551/175515) is degenerate, and so I used the following to calculate the density that results from the normal approximation:

There's a theorem that says given a random variable $X = [X_1, \ldots, X_m]^T \sim \text{Multinom}(n, p)$, for an $m$-dimensional vector $p$ with $\sum_i p_i = 1$ and $\sum_i X_i = n$, that;

$$ 
  X
  \xrightarrow{d} \sqrt{n} \, \text{diag}(u) \, Q
  \begin{bmatrix}
      Z_1 \\ \vdots \\ Z_{m-1} \\ 0
  \end{bmatrix} +
  \begin{bmatrix} n p_1 \\ \vdots \\ n p_m \end{bmatrix},
$$

for large $n$, given;

- a vector $u$ with $u_i = \sqrt{p_i}$;
- random variables $Z_i \sim N(0,1)$ for $i = 1, \ldots, m-1$, and;
- an orthogonal matrix $Q$ with final column $u$.

That is to say, with some rearrangement, we can work out an $m-1$ dimensional multivariate normal distribution for the first $m-1$ components of $X$ (which are the only interesting components because $X_m$ is the sum of the others).

A suitable value of the matrix $Q$ is $I - 2 v v^T$ with $v_i = (\delta_{im} - u_i) / \sqrt{2(1 - u_m)}$ - i.e. a particular Householder transformation.

If we restrict the left-hand side to the first $m-1$ rows, and restrict $Q$ to its first $m-1$ rows and $m-1$ columns (denote these $\hat{X}$ and $\hat{Q}$ respectively) then:

$$ 
  \hat{X}
  \xrightarrow{d} \sqrt{n} \text{diag}(\hat{u}) \hat{Q}
  \begin{bmatrix}
      Z_1 \\ \vdots \\ Z_{m-1}
  \end{bmatrix} +
  \begin{bmatrix} n p_1 \\ \vdots \\ n p_{m-1} \end{bmatrix}
  \sim
  \mathcal{N} \left( \mu, n \Sigma \right),
$$

for large $n$, where;

- $\hat{u}$ denotes the first $m-1$ terms of $u$;
- the mean is $\mu = [ n p_1, \ldots, n p_{m-1}]^T$, and;
- the covariance matrix $n \Sigma = n A A^T$ with $A = \text{diag}( \hat{u} ) \hat{Q}$.

The right hand side of that final equation is the non-degenerate density used in calculation.

As expected, when you plug everything in, you get the following covariance matrix:

$$ (n\Sigma)_{ij} = n \sqrt{p_i p_j} (\delta_{ij} - \sqrt{p_i p_j}) $$

for $i,j = 1, \ldots, m-1$, which is *exactly* the covariance matrix in the original answer restricted to its first $m-1$ rows and $m-1$ columns.

This [blog entry](https://aloneinthefart.blogspot.com/2012/09/normal-approximation-of-multinomial.html) was my starting point.

Comment: Another useful resource is the links provided in: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2397/asymptotic-distribution-of-multinomial

Comment: Good answer (+1) --- Note that you can embed links with the syntax ```[textual description](hyperlink)```.  I have taken the liberty of editing this answer to embed your links.