# Linear transformation of a random variable by a tall rectangular matrix

Tags: references, random-variable, density-function, linear

Let's say we have a random vector $\vec{X} \in \mathbb{R}^n$, drawn from a distribution with probability density function $f_\vec{X}(\vec{x})$. If we linearly transform it by a full-rank $n \times n$ matrix $A$ to get $\vec{Y} = A\vec{X}$, then the density of $\vec{Y}$ is given by $$
f_{\vec{Y}}(\vec{y}) = \frac{1}{\left|\det A\right|}f_{\vec{X}}(A^{-1}\vec{y}).
$$

Now say we transform $\vec{X}$ instead by an $m \times n$ matrix $B$, with $m > n$, giving $\vec{Z} = B\vec{X}$. Clearly $Z \in \mathbb{R}^m$, but it "lives on" an $n$-dimensional subspace $G \subset \mathbb{R}^m$. What is the conditional density of $\vec{Z}$, given that we know it lies in $G$?

My first instinct was to use the pseudo-inverse of $B$. If $B = U S V^T$ is the singular value decomposition of $B$, then $B^+ = V S^+ U^T$ is the pseudo-inverse, where $S^+$ is formed by inverting the non-zero entries of the diagonal matrix $S$. I guessed that this would give $$
f_\vec{Z}(\vec{z}) = \frac{1}{\left|\det^+ S\right|} f_\vec{X}(B^+ \vec{z}),
$$
where by $\det^+ S$ I mean the product of the non-zero singular values.

This reasoning agrees with the density for a singular normal (conditioned on knowledge that the variable lives on the appropriate subspace) given [here](http://sfb649.wiwi.hu-berlin.de/fedc_homepage/xplore/tutorials/mvahtmlnode34.html) and mentioned [also here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sci.stat.math/rdaH8qdBxfY) and in [this CrossValidated post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2397/asymptotic-distribution-of-multinomial).

But it isn't right! The normalization constant is off. A (trivial) counterexample is given by considering the following case: With $X \sim \mathcal{N(0, 1)}$, let $$
\vec{Y} = \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix} X = \begin{pmatrix}X \\ X\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Here the matrix $B$ from above is just the ones vector. Its pseudo-inverse is $$
B^+ = \begin{pmatrix}1/2 & 1/2\end{pmatrix}
$$
and $\det^+ B = \sqrt{2}$. The reasoning from above would suggest $$
f_\vec{Y}(\vec{y}) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sqrt{2}}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\vec{y}^T (B^+)^T B^+ \vec{y}\right),
$$
but this in fact integrates (on the line $y = x$) to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. I realize in this case you could just drop one of the entries of $\vec{Y}$ you're done, but when $B$ is much larger identifying the set of entries to drop is annoying. Why doesn't the pseudo-inverse reasoning work? Is there a general formula for the density function of a linear transformation of a set of random variables by a "tall" matrix? Any references would be greatly appreciated as well.

Answer (score 6):

For those who might run across this in the future... the source of the error actually stems from the integration. In the example above, integration takes place over the line $y = x$. It is therefore necessary to "parametrize" the line and consider the Jacobian of the parametrization when taking the integral, since each unit step in the $x$-axis corresponds to steps of length $\sqrt{2}$ on the line. The parametrization I was implicitly using was given by $x \mapsto (x, x)$, in other words specifying both identical entries of $\vec{y}$ by value. This has Jacobian $\sqrt{2}$, which neatly cancels with the $\sqrt{2}$ (coming from exactly the same Jacobian) in the denominator.

The example was artificially simple — for a general transformation $B$, one may have another parametrization for the output that is natural in the context of the problem. Since the parametrization needs to cover the same subspace $G$ as $B$, and this subspace is a hyperplane, the parameterization is itself likely to be linear. Calling the $m \times n$ matrix representation of the parametrization $L$, the requirement is simply that it have the same column space as $B$ (cover the same hyperplane). Then the final density becomes $$
f_{\vec{Z}}(\vec{z}) = \frac{\left|\det^+ L\right|}{\left|\det^+ B\right|}f_{\vec{X}}(B^+ \vec{z}).
$$

In general, this setup is kind of odd, and I think the right thing to do is to find a maximal linearly independent set of rows of $B$, and remove the rest of the rows (along with the corresponding components of the transformed variable $\vec{z}$) to get a square matrix $\hat B$. Then the problem reduces to the full-rank $n \times n$ case (assuming $B$ has full column rank).