# Linear transformation of a random vector with pseudo-inverse

Tags: random-variable, linear, linear-algebra

If $$ \mathbf{X} = (X_1,..,X_n)^t$$ is a random variable drawn according to a probability density function (pdf) $$ f_{X_1,...,X_n}(x_1,...,x_n) $$ then $$ \mathbf{Y} = A\mathbf{X} = (Y_1,..,Y_n)^t$$ with $A$ a square non-singular matrix, has a pdf given by:
$$ f_{Y_1,...,Y_n}(y_1,...,y_n)=\frac{f_\mathbf{X}(A^{-1} \mathbf{y})}{|A|} $$
I have heard that this can be generalised to the case of a non-square matrix with the Moore–Penrose pseudo-inverse concept, where now $$ \mathbf{Y} = A\mathbf{X} = (Y_1,..,Y_m)^t \qquad m<n $$
and 
$$ f_{Y_1,...,Y_m}(y_1,...,y_m)=\frac{f_\mathbf{X}(A^{+} \mathbf{y})}{|A|_{+}} $$ 
with $A^+$ the pseudo-inverse of $A$ and $|A|_{+}$ the pseudo-determinant.

If this is right, how can it be proved? and more important, what is the intuition behind this generalisation?
I've only found [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/134935/linear-transformation-of-a-random-variable-by-a-tall-rectangular-matrix) related question, but I can't understand how the OP finds the general expression for $f_{Y_1,...,Y_m}(y_1,...,y_m)$.

Comment: It's a good question, but I think you haven't formulated things quite right: your formulas for $f_Y$ make no sense, because the arguments are $y_1,\ldots, $ but the right hand sides don't involve these arguments at all.

Comment: I made a mistake writing the expression of the transformed random variable. Now I think it's ok. Thanks for pointing that out! @whuber